# Path appears to be correct for image, yet my svg is not being displayed

Tags: reactjs, image, file

I am trying to display a search icon in my react app.

In my SearchIcon component I have an img tag:

```
<SearchIcon>
    <img src="/images/search-icon.svg" alt=""/>
</SearchIcon>
```

My icon is not being displayed though.

My SearchIcon component is in my ProjectFile->src->Profiles->EmployerHeader.js file.

My search-icon.svg is located in ProjectFile->public->images->search-icon.svg

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing will search for the file inside images folder which is inside Profiles folder. That will not work obviously.

`..` means up one level. You have to go up two levels to your Project folder and then search.

`"../../public/images/search-icon.svg"`